# Permissions on Server Reset, Why?

Tags: windows-server-2003, dfs

I have a Windows 2003 domain controller that we needed to take down in order to move it.  When it was brought back up DFS wasn't working, our previous shares were marked as disabled.  It turns out that the sharing permissions had been reset to basic read.  By changing them to read/write and restarting the DFS service the shares could be enabled again in DFS.

What is bugging us is how/why did the permissions reset?  Nobody touched them, and they shouldn't have been reset just from bringing the server down, correct?

Comment: Did the IP or name of this server change after the move?  And also, while not an answer to your question, this is another good example of why you shouldn't pile other services or roles onto a Domain Controller (with the possible exception of DHCP, depending on who you ask).

Comment: Well DFS is so lightweight it really shouldn't be an issue (in my opinion).  The server name and IP remained the same.  It may also be worth mentioning the folders in question are on SAN LUNs and not local hard drives.

Comment: It's not a performance issue, it's a complexity issue.  Not being an AD expert, or having all the details of your setup, all I can really say is "hmmm, weird things happen when you run other services on a Domain Controller."